# Resolving error with Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: python, r

For the code below:

```
` library(cluster)

    silhouette_scores <- sapply(2:10, function(k) {
  km <- kmeans(iris[, 1:4], centers = k)
  silhouette(km$cluster, dist(iris[, 1:4]))
})


    plot(2:10, silhouette_scores, type = "b", xlab = "Number of     Clusters",
     ylab = "Silhouette Score", main = "Silhouette Plot")`
```

I am getting the following error:

```
`    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
    Traceback:

    1. plot(2:10, silhouette_scores, type = "b", xlab = "Number of Clusters", 
 .     ylab = "Silhouette Score", main = "Silhouette Plot")
    2. plot(2:10, silhouette_scores, type = "b", xlab = "Number of Clusters", 
 .     ylab = "Silhouette Score", main = "Silhouette Plot")
    3. plot.default(2:10, silhouette_scores, type = "b", xlab = "Number of Clusters", 
 .     ylab = "Silhouette Score", main = "Silhouette Plot")
    4. xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log)
    5. stop("'x' and 'y' lengths differ")`
```

I am trying to use the Iris dataset in R to calculate silhouette scores and then create a silhouette plot to determine the number of clusters there would be after having done k-means clustering on the first two principal components of the data. PCA was done but now it is showing this error so I want to know how I can plot k=2 through k=10.

I tried to rectify it by adding plot(x, y[1:length(x)]) before the last line of code, but it didn't work. Would anyone know of another fix?